# Add a list of regions to Vimeo using PyVimeo in django

Tags: python, django, vimeo, vimeo-api, pyvimeo

I have a django app in which i am using [`PyVimeo`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyVimeo/0.3.0) module to connect and upload videos etc., to `Vimeo`

The actual vimeo api to post the region data was [here](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/playground/ondemand/pages/47753/regions/AL)

For example i have the following data `[{u'country_name': u'CA'}, {u'country_name': u'US'}]` to send a `PUT` request to the url `https://api.vimeo.com/ondemand/pages/47753/regions`

From code i was trying to send PUT request as below

```
import vimeo

token = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
VIMEO_KEY = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
VIMEO_SECRET = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
client = vimeo.VimeoClient(key=VIMEO_KEY, secret=VIMEO_SECRET, token=token)

url = https://api.vimeo.com/ondemand/pages/47753/regions
regions_data = [{u'country_name': u'CA'}, {u'country_name': u'US'}]

result_data = client.put(url, regions_data)
```

Response was `400 Bad request`

When tried in the below way as indicated in the Vimeo API docs

```
client.put(url + 'CA')
```

Response

```
HTTP/1.1 201
Location: Array
Host: api.vimeo.com
```

But it was not reflecting in the Distribution section of the video setting and being as `Worldwide` by default

So how actually to set a list of regions to a on demand page VOD ?

Comment: The batch PUT to https://api.vimeo.com/ondemand/pages/47753/regions looks correct, I'll have to dig into why that's not working. The PUT to a single region only enables that region. It will not disable other regions, so since you are available worldwide, the region is already enabled and you will see no change.

Comment: @Dashron Thanks very much for replying, yeah we are really facing the problem with Vimeo Client to post the territories, by the way it was working from postman when use raw data with content type as application/json

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `country_code` instead of `country_name`

```
v = vimeo.VimeoClient(key=YOUR_VIMEO_KEY,
                      secret=YOUR_VIMEO_SECRET,
                      token=YOUR_VIMEO_TOKEN)

regions_data = [{'country_code': 'CA'}, {'country_code': 'US'}]

output = v.put('/ondemand/pages/mytestvod/regions', data=regions_data)
```

This should restrict distribution to only Canada and the US.